# Blazor equivalent to WPFs ItemsControl+DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, razor, blazor

In WPF I can via `DataTemplates` automatically get my content displayed in different templates, depending on it's types.

For example, I have two classes `ChildAViewModel` and `ChildBViewModel` that both implement the `IChild` interface. A parent now has a `List<IChild>` that holds different instances of `ChildAViewModel` and `ChildBViewModel`.

```
    public interface IChild
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildAViewModel : IChild
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildBViewModel : IChild
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentViewModel
    {
        public ParentViewModel()
        {
            Children = new();
            Children.Add(new ChildAViewModel() { Name = "ernie" });
            Children.Add(new ChildBViewModel() { Name = "bert" });
        }
        List<IChild> Children { get; set;}
    }
```

In the view of the parent I can now bind the child classes to `DataTemplate`s and display my `List<IChild>` in an `ItemsControl`.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildAViewModel}">
            <!--  something  -->
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildBViewModel}">
            <!--  something different  -->
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

So I get each child displayed in the right template.

However, how can I archive the same result in Blazor/ Razor: One list of different classes but the same interface displayed in different UI elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XAML and Razor are two totally different things so there is no real equivalent but in Blazor you have a lot more flexibility to do things directly in the markup. You could for example `switch` directly on the type:

```
@foreach (var item in Children)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case ChildAViewModel:
            <div>template a...</div>
            break;
        case ChildBViewModel:
            <div>template b...</div>
            break;
    }
}
```

You may also add two different [template parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/components#templated-components?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) to your component.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I meant. Sorry that I got a little to deep into wpf, but I had trouble to express what my goal was, so I just showed some code how I would solve the problem in wpf. Your solution however is the perfect starting point and just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ModelToComponentMapper